Convergence of Sequences with respect to Ultrafilters on the Natural numbers in Compact Hausdorff Topological Spaces
Let $(X,\mathcal T)$ be a topological space.
Let $\mathcal F$ be an ultrafilter on $\mathbb N$.

We say that sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges with respect to $\mathcal F$ to $x$, iff for all open neighbourhoods $\mathcal U$ of $x$,
the set $\left\{n\in\mathbb N\mid x_n\in\mathcal U\right\}$ is in the ultrafilter $\mathcal F$.

Let $\lim_\limits{\mathcal F}(x_n)$ be the collection of $x\in X$ such that $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ with respect to $\mathcal F$.
I am trying to show that for any sequence $x_n \in X$:

if $X$ is compact, $\lim_\limits{\mathcal F}(x_n)$ is not empty; and
if $X$ is Hausdorff, $\lim_\limits{\mathcal F}(x_n)$ is at most singleton.

I have no idea of proving these statements.
I have tried to separate by cases. If $\mathcal F$ is a principal ultrafilter, then it has a least element $n$, so converges with respect to $\mathcal F$ to $x_n$ and being Hausdorff will guarantee uniqueness. However, I do not know how to deal with free ultrafilters.
Alternatively, I try to argue that for all $x\in X$, there exists a neighbourhood $\mathcal U_x$, and by compactness there exists a finite subcover. However, I have seen the case where the ultrafilter is on $X$; I do not know how to proceed with sequences.
Thanks.

These "for all ultrafilters $\mathcal{U}$" make no sense to me. Do they make sense to you?

@AndréCaldas Fixed for the OP - it was obvious what it meant.

@DavidGao: for me and for you that have already done this exercise, it was obvious. For the OP, whose background I do not know, I am not sure it was obvious. I was trying to help the OP. The post was full of "for all xxx". Instead of doing the "obvious fix", I have removed them. I intended the OP to do it, but...

Thanks! This is exactly what I am trying to say but cleaner.

For part $1$, assume $X$ is compact. Assume to the contrary that $\lim_\limits{\mathcal{F}} (x_n)$ is empty. Then by definition of convergence w.r.t. $\mathcal{F}$, we see that for any $x \in X$, there is an open neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ s.t. $\{n \in \mathbb{N}: x_n \in U_x\} \notin \mathcal{F}$. By compactness, there is a finite set $\{x_1, \cdots, x_n\}$ s.t. $\cup_{i=1}^n U_{x_n} = X$. But this means that,
$$\mathbb{N} = \{n \in \mathbb{N}: x_n \in \cup_{i=1}^n U_{x_n}\} = \bigcup_{i=1}^n \{n \in \mathbb{N}: x_n \in U_{x_n}\}$$
is a finite union of sets not in $\mathcal{F}$. As $\mathcal{F}$ is an ultrafilter, this means $\mathbb{N} \notin \mathcal{F}$, a contradiction. Thus, $\lim_\limits{\mathcal{F}} (x_n)$ must be nonempty.
For part $2$, assume to the contrary that $\lim_\limits{\mathcal{F}}(x_n)$ contains two distinct points $x, y$. Since $X$ is Hausdorff, there exists $U_x$, open neighborhood of $x$, and $U_y$, open neighborhood of $y$, s.t. $U_x \cap U_y = \varnothing$. But then,
$$\varnothing = \{n \in \mathbb{N}: x_n \in U_x \cap U_y\} = \{n \in \mathbb{N}: x_n \in U_x\} \cap \{n \in \mathbb{N}: x_n \in U_y\}$$
As $x, y \in \lim_\limits{\mathcal{F}} (x_n)$, both sets on the RHS are in $\mathcal{F}$, whence $\varnothing \in \mathcal{F}$, a contradiction. Thus, $\lim_\limits{\mathcal{F}} (x_n)$ has at most $1$ element.

Nice! I love the characterization of an ultrafilter as a filter such that if a finite union is in it, then some member of that union is also in it. Or the negation... a finite union of things that are not in it cannot be in it.
